# HQL result not returning null Data

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have HQL query which is returning List.

```
    Account_no, Account_name,Account_type,Account_date
    1             xyz          Saving       12/12/1982
    2             null          Recurring    null
```

HQL when returning the data it is not giving me null data.

```
    Select * from Account_table
    return List = [0]= [[0]=1,[1]=xyz,[2]=Saving,[3]=12/12/1982]
                  [1]= [[0]=2,[2]=Recurring]
```

It didnt return me the null values.
Please let me know what I need to change to get all nullable data too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you've already set the default value for column "Account_date", and null means nothing (there's no value), that's why it's not returning any value.

Comment: Thats correct but it should return me null values atleast. If I change my filter condition to left outer join  it is returning me null data too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are iterating over the array data you have shown then you should find that the nulls are there. Are you doing something like this?

```
// [0] = [[0]=1,[1]=xyz,[2]=Saving,[3]=12/12/1982]
// [1] = [[0]=2,[2]=Recurring]

for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    MyAccount acct = new MyAccount();
    acct.setAccountNo((Integer) results[i][0]);
    acct.setName((String) results[i][1]); 
        // and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
for(Object entity : list){
                Object[] obj = (Object[]) entity;
                MyAccount acct = new MyAccount();
                acct.setAccount(obj[0]!=null ? obj[0].toString() : "do something else");
}
```

In the "so something else" part do your stuff.